# Vuex Getters duplicating array values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

I have a simple lesson creator where I allow teachers to make selections for various categories, those selections ids are collected and grouped together and I want to return them all at the end as a lesson plan.

However, I am having a strange problem that I can't figure out. My Vuex store shows the selections correctly, however my getter duplicates all of my arrays.

After selections are made, my Vuex store shows something like this through the Vue.js dev-tools plugin:

```
lesson_store:Object
    lesson:Object
        selected_event:1
        selected_exploration:Array[1]
            0:1
        selected_extensions:Array[1]
            0:1
        selected_goals:Array[1]
            0:54
        selected_lexis:Array[1]
            0:2
```

`store.js` state and getter:

```
const state = {
    lesson: {
        selected_event: '',
        selected_exploration: [],
        selected_extensions: [],
        selected_goals: [],
        selected_lexis: [],
    }
};

getSelections(state) {
    console.log('GETTER SELECTIONS', state.lesson);
    return state.lesson
}
```

My call to `getSelections` from `lesson.vue` file:

```
<template><button @click="saveLesson">Save</button></template>


methods: {
    saveLesson () {
        console.log('GET RETURN OF SELECTIONS',this.$store.getters["getSelections"]);
    },
}
```

Now my console output is:

```
lesson_store:Object
    lesson:Object
        selected_event:1
        selected_exploration:Array[2]
            0:1
            0:1
        selected_extensions:Array[2]
            0:1
            0:1
        selected_goals:Array[2]
            0:54
            0:54
        selected_lexis:Array[2]
            0:2
            0:2
```

The thing is, none of my other getters behave this way. This getter is super basic.
When I check out store and `getSelections` getter in the Vue.js dev-tools the values are correct and there are no duplicates.

Any advice or direction you can provide would be much appreciated.

UPDATE::::::

Actions and Mutations for Lesson_Store

```
// create mutations
const mutations = {
    setSelectedEvent(state, payload) {
        // state.lesson.selected_event = payload

        if (state.lesson.selected_event === payload) {

            state.lesson.selected_event = '';
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_event = payload
        }

    },

    setSelectedReading(state, payload) {

        if (state.lesson.selected_reading === payload) {
            state.lesson.selected_reading = '';
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_reading = payload
        }

    },

    setSelectedLexis(state, payload) {

        // if event is already in array, then remove it with filter
        // otherwise push it to the array
        if (state.lesson.selected_lexis.includes(payload)) {
            state.lesson.selected_lexis = state.lesson.selected_lexis.filter(function (item) {
                return item !== payload;
            });
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_lexis.push(payload);
        }

        // state.lesson.selected_lexis = payload
    },

    setSelectedExplorations(state, payload) {

        // if event is already in array, then remove it with filter
        // otherwise push it to the array
        if (state.lesson.selected_exploration.includes(payload)) {
            state.lesson.selected_exploration = state.lesson.selected_exploration.filter(function (item) {
                return item !== payload;
            });
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_exploration.push(payload);
        }

        // state.lesson.selected_lexis = payload
    },

    setSelectedQuestions(state, payload) {

        // if event is already in array, then remove it with filter
        // otherwise push it to the array
        if (state.lesson.selected_questions.includes(payload)) {
            state.lesson.selected_questions = state.lesson.selected_questions.filter(function (item) {
                return item !== payload;
            });
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_questions.push(payload);
        }

        // state.lesson.selected_lexis = payload
    },

    setSelectedPerformances(state, payload) {

        // if event is already in array, then remove it with filter
        // otherwise push it to the array
        if (state.lesson.selected_performances.includes(payload)) {
            state.lesson.selected_performances = state.lesson.selected_performances.filter(function (item) {
                return item !== payload;
            });
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_performances.push(payload);
        }

    },

    setSelectedExtensions(state, payload) {

        // if event is already in array, then remove it with filter
        // otherwise push it to the array
        if (state.lesson.selected_extensions.includes(payload)) {
            state.lesson.selected_extensions = state.lesson.selected_extensions.filter(function (item) {
                return item !== payload;
            });
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_extensions.push(payload);
        }

    },

    setSelectedGoals(state, payload) {

        // if event is already in array, then remove it with filter
        // otherwise push it to the array
        if (state.lesson.selected_goals.includes(payload)) {
            state.lesson.selected_goals = state.lesson.selected_goals.filter(function (item) {
                return item !== payload;
            });
        } else {
            state.lesson.selected_goals.push(payload);
        }

    },


};

// create actions
const actions = {
    setSelectedEvent({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedEvent', payload);
    },

    setSelectedReading({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedReading', payload);
    },

    setSelectedLexis({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedLexis', payload);
    },

    setSelectedExplorations({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedExplorations', payload);
    },

    setSelectedQuestions({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedQuestions', payload);
    },

    setSelectedPerformances({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedPerformances', payload);
    },

    setSelectedExtensions({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedExtensions', payload);
    },

    setSelectedGoals({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSelectedGoals', payload);
    },
};
```

All of these appear to be working correctly because my vuejs dev tools display all of the selection id's properly.

Comment: I am not sure if it matters but this lesson_store is in a module that is imported.

Comment: Where do you call `saveLesson()`?

Comment: I added a button in lesson.vue file <button @click="saveLesson">Save</button> I also tried to just load the data when created() but it creates the same duplication

Comment: That's odd. What about your action and mutation that sets the data? Could you post those?

Comment: I updated with the Mutations and Actions, there are more fields than my simplified version but all array fields are duplicating the ID values, if I have one two or three selections, they will be duplicated to two, four and six respectively.

Comment: Ignoring the dev-tools output, are you sure your `if` statements are evaluating how you expect? The only thing I can see that might cause this is with your mutations pushing the same value in each `else` block

Comment: I guess that is possible, but I don't know how to evaluate that without the dev tools. The functionality I program is working correctly in that if I click on an item, it is added to the list of selections, the selection list is evaluated and it sets active class which highlights element in the UI, if item is clicked again they are removed  from the selection list and highlight is removed. I console logged add and remove in my if logic and it appears to be working correctly. Is there another way to other than dev tools you would recommend to evaluate my store values that you would recommend?

Comment: You could try [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) but if everything points to it working properly other than the console log I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel_Knights thanks for the input there was some funky circular logic happening in my if statements that created strange behaviors. I tried to give you an upvote on your comment so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone having similar issues where your dev tools store does not match your actual store values output, it is probably due to your code not updating the store values formally through the actions and mutations approach.

if this store value is ever updated directly without actions and mutations the value in the store will change, however, those updated values will not be detected by vuejs dev tools and your actual store data and dev tools data values will not match.